# How can I retrieve listings based on cumulative total to a column value?

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have a 'project' table which has an integer value, `budget` column.

I want to generate users for this specific project. Now users have a `salary`, and I want to find 'x' users with salaries that can fit that budget.

I can't figure out how I would write an SQL statement (or multiple) to do this, so any help would be well and truly appreciated!

---

**EDIT:**

I will eventually need to sort the ultimate list of users by their skills associated with the project. Therefore maybe the best thing to do is return all listings of x users which match the budget. Then I can apply further conditions to the number of groups of listings.

---

Thanks

Comment: how can we figure it out if you don't show some sample data and explain the rules?

Comment: There are many combinations of employees who fit that criteria.  How do choose among those combinations.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all combinations of employees that fit in the budget with a series of joins.  For instance, if x = 3:

```
select p.project_id, p.budget,
       (e1.salary + e2.salary + e3.salary) as total_salary,
       e1.employee_id, e2.employee_id, e3.employee_id
from employees e1 join
     employees e2
     on e1.employee_id < e2.employee_id join
     employees e3
     on e2.employee_id < e3.employee_id join
     projects p
     on (e1.salary + e2.salary + e3.salary) < p.budget;
```